# How do I switch from one fragment to another when a list item is clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a list in "All Users" Fragment. When a name on list is clicked, It should switch to "User Details" Fragment. I can't seem to find a way to somehow destroy this fragment and bring up the new one, or just display the new one on top of old.

The language used is Kotlin. I'm new to this. I tried some ways with Fragment Manager but can't seem to figure out the right syntax.

Main Activity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Default view when app starts
        title = resources.getString(R.string.allusers)
        loadFragment(AllUsersFragment())

        //Bottom Navigation Bar
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_allusers -> {
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.allusers)
                    loadFragment(AllUsersFragment())
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.navigation_transfer -> {
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.transfer)
                    loadFragment(TransferFragment())
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

                R.id.navigation_logs -> {
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.logs)
                    loadFragment(LogsFragment())
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }

            }
            false

        }
    }

    //function to load fragment when bottom navigation is clicked

    fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

}
```

AllUsersFragment.kt

```
class AllUsersFragment : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var listView:ListView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allusers, container, false)
        val details = UserDetailsFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()                //To transfer information

        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList)

        val userNames = arrayOf(
            "Andrew Jackson",
            "Barry Alan",
            "Caitlyn Snow",
            "Drake Ramoray"
        )

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userNames)
        listView.adapter = adapter

        //List view item clicked listener
        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

            val userName = userNames[i]
            bundle.putString("str", userName)
            bundle.putInt("int", i)
            details.arguments = bundle
        }

        return rootView
    }
}
```

UserDetails.kt

```
class UserDetailsFragment : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_details,container,false)

        val nameField = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nameField)
        val imageField = rootView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageField)

        //Importing images
        val andrewjackson = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context!!.resources,R.drawable.andrewjackson)
        val barryalan = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context!!.resources,R.drawable.barryalan)
        val caitlynsnow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context!!.resources,R.drawable.caitlynsnow)
        val drakeramoray = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context!!.resources,R.drawable.drakeramoray)

        val userImages = ArrayList<Bitmap>()

        userImages.add(andrewjackson)
        userImages.add(barryalan)
        userImages.add(caitlynsnow)
        userImages.add(drakeramoray)

        val name = arguments!!.getString("str")     //Displays name clicked on Details Page
        nameField.setText(name)

        val i =arguments!!.getInt("int")               //Displays image of user from array
        imageField.setImageBitmap(userImages[i])

        return rootView
    }
}
```

I think using the `loadFragment` function in `MainActivity.kt` it might be possible, but I can't figure out a way to use that inside the fragment.

Expected Output:

When a name on the list is clicked, it should change to another fragment in the same container, that displays user details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your fragment to replace the fragment in your container

```
val someFragment = YourUserDetailsFragment()
val transaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.container, someFragment)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There are two ways using Interface and by the public method. As your fragment is bound with the activity that means it's the parent is activity.

So you can access the method just to make public inactivity and access by using

```
(activity as MainActivity).loadFragment(//Your fragment intance)
```

[Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities-dc91707e02fb) is the example to communicate between activity and fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You already have everything set up, in your, on click listener you should just call     `activity?.loadFragment(UserDetailsFragment())`

```
 listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        val userName = userNames[i]
        bundle.putString("str", userName)
        bundle.putInt("int", i)
        details.arguments = bundle
        (activity as MainActivity)?.loadFragment(details)
    }
```